# Why $aliasArr is always an array if there is no comma on the string?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$str = "one, two, three ,four";
$str = "one";

echo $str . PHP_EOL;

$noWhiteSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
$aliasArr = explode(',', $noWhiteSpaces);

echo is_array($aliasArr) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

The idea behind is simple: if string `$str` has comma (,) then `$aliasArr` will be an array otherwise it will be false. If you test the code using the first `$str` you will see how you get `TRUE` as output but if you try with the second one  (which overrides the previous one) you will see `TRUE` also which I think is wrong, I am right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `explode` function returns array, so check the length of the array `echo sizeof($aliasArr) > 1 ? 'true' : 'false';` (The length will be 1 if the splitting value was not found)

Answer (score 3):

Once you explode it you get an array with one element.  It is always an array after that.  Another approach might be to check the length of the array to determine if it has only one element or more than one element.

Answer (score 2):

`explode()` always returns an array – even if it's only one element, see [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Just replace `is_array($aliasArr)` with

```
count($aliasArr) > 1
```

To get the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Two things:-**

1.`(,)` is called `comma` not `column` (May be typo mistake in your question)

2.Whenever you `explode()` you will always got an array (either one element array or array with more than one value).

So you need to check `echo (sizeof($aliasArr)>1) ? 'true' : 'false';`

Or you can use `count($aliasArr)>1` also